# generate a chart/graph in application using vb.net using excel worksheet data

Tags: vb.net

How to generate a chart/graph in an application using vb.net using excel worksheet data?

I have a listview function that is already linking up the excel data and now wish to select certain data and create a line graph showing the results.

In listview I have each of the headings linked as a string.

Can a connection be made with either the ListViewItem or with the original Excel Worksheet. I want the graph to show on the general application form that has been created and not in an active Excel sheet.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be ale to just databind whatever data you want in the listview with the chart. Can you give more details on how you want to select the data?
This shows Databinding (just pass in two arrays): [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455475(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You could have two comboBoxes with the name of the potential x-values and the name of the potential y-values, and update the chart whenever one of the selected items changes.